# Regarding drop in test accuracy of one fold in 5 fold cross validation

Tags: cross-validation, accuracy

I am training and testing a convolution neural network for binomial classification with 5 fold cross-validation. The data set has 4684 3 dimensional arrays of shape (2000,102,1). This is a sparse data set with values between 0 and 1 in only one column of a row. The network consists of one cnn layer, maxplooling, drop out, fully connected and finally output layer. I also set aside 0.1 percent of training data for validation. Sorry, I am unable to provide code as this is for research purpose.

I am looking to understand why suddenly one fold test accuracy of my 5 fold cross validation falls to 0. I see that the 4 folds are giving 95 percent test accuracy but one fold is giving 0 test accuracy.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome.  It's possible to guess, but a really informed answer, and one that'd likely be useful to other readers as well, would require much more information from you.  Have you read https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/how-to-ask-a-good-question-on-crossvalidated ?

Comment: What is the ratio of 0/1 in your dataset ? If it is imbalanced are you using stratified folds? Can you share the results of each fold like accuracy as you mentioned, some other metrics as well ?